# Removing a section from ToC pushes section away from numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

Hi when I add a star to a section it pushes the section title downwards like so:
[image: badly alligned section]

this is the command I use: `\section*{Figures}`

Im guessing it has something to do with my preamble, but as I recieved a template I don't know where to look! Hope someone can help me out! :)

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside]{memoir}  % Openright aabner kapitler paa hoejresider (openany begge)


%%%% EGNE KOMMANDOER %%%%
\input{Setup/CustomCommand}


%%%% PAKKER %%%%
% ¤¤ Oversaettelse og tegnsaetning ¤¤ %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Input-indkodning af tegnsaet (UTF8)
\usepackage[english]{babel}                 % Dokumentets sprog
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % Output-indkodning af tegnsaet (T1)
\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}           % Justering af elementer
% ¤¤ Figurer og tabeller (floats) ¤¤ %
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % Haandtering af eksterne billeder (JPG, PNG, PDF)
\usepackage{multirow}                       % Fletning af raekker og kolonner (\multicolumn og \multirow)
\usepackage{colortbl}                       % Farver i tabeller (fx \columncolor, \rowcolor og \cellcolor)
\usepackage{hhline}                         % Opsætning til tabel
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,longtable,x11names]{xcolor} % Definer farver med \definecolor. Se mere: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors
\usepackage{flafter}                        % Soerger for at floats ikke optraeder i teksten foer deres reference
\let\newfloat\relax                         % Justering mellem float-pakken og memoir
\usepackage{float}                          % Muliggoer eksakt placering af floats, f.eks. 
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{scrextend}                      % labeling lister

%Code blocks%
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{minted}

% ¤¤ Matematik mm. ¤¤
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       % Avancerede matematik-udvidelser
\usepackage{mathtools}                      % Andre matematik- og tegnudvidelser
\usepackage{textcomp}                       % Symbol-udvidelser (f.eks. promille-tegn med \textperthousand )
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % Flot og konsistent praesentation af tal og enheder med \si{enhed} og \SI{tal}{enhed}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}       % Opsaetning af \SI (DE for komma som decimalseparator) 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}              % Kemi-pakke til flot og let notation af formler, f.eks. \ce{Fe2O3}

% ¤¤ Referencer og kilder ¤¤ %
\usepackage[danish]{varioref}               % Muliggoer bl.a. krydshenvisninger med sidetal (\vref)
\usepackage{xr}                         % Referencer til eksternt dokument med \externaldocument{<NAVN>}
%\usepackage{glossaries}                    % Terminologi- eller symbolliste (se mere i Daleifs Latex-bog)

% ¤¤ Misc. ¤¤ %
\usepackage{listings}                       % Placer kildekode i dokumentet med \begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         % Dummy text \lipsum[..]
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}          % Muliggoer enkelt konfiguration af lister
\usepackage{pdfpages}   % Goer det muligt at inkludere pdf-dokumenter med kommandoen \includepdf[pages={x-y}]{fil.pdf}
\usepackage{longtable}

%SVG images%
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Referencer
\usepackage{url}
    
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6                 % Muliggoer inkludering af pdf dokumenter, af version 1.6 og hoejere
\pretolerance=2500                          % Justering af afstand mellem ord (hoejt tal, mindre orddeling og mere luft mellem ord)     

%%%% BRUGERDEFINEREDE INDSTILLINGER %%%%

% ¤¤ Marginer ¤¤ %
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}      % \setlrmarginsandblock{Indbinding}{Kant}{Ratio}
\setulmarginsandblock{1.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}      % \setulmarginsandblock{Top}{Bund}{Ratio}
\checkandfixthelayout                       % Oversaetter vaerdier til brug for andre pakker

%   ¤¤ Afsnitsformatering ¤¤ %
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                 % Stoerrelse af indryk
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}                   % Afstand mellem afsnit ved brug af double Enter
\linespread{1,1}                            % Linie afstand

% ¤¤ Litteraturlisten ¤¤ %
%\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,}             % Definerer de 6 parametre ved Harvard henvisning (bl.a. parantestype og seperatortegn)
%\bibliographystyle{plain}                      % Udseende af litteraturlisten.
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}


% ¤¤ Indholdsfortegnelse ¤¤ %
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}                 % Dybden af nummerede overkrifter (part/chapter/section/subsection)
\maxsecnumdepth{subsection}                 % Dokumentklassens graense for nummereringsdybde
\settocdepth{subsection}                    % Dybden af indholdsfortegnelsen

% ¤¤ Lister ¤¤ %
\setlist{
  topsep=0pt,                               % Vertikal afstand mellem tekst og listen
  itemsep=-1ex,                             % Vertikal afstand mellem items
} 

% ¤¤ Visuelle referencer ¤¤ %
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}          % Danner klikbare referencer (hyperlinks) i dokumentet.
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,              % Opsaetning af farvede hyperlinks (interne links, citeringer og URL)
    linkcolor = black,
    citecolor = black,
    urlcolor = black
}

% ¤¤ Opsaetning af figur- og tabeltekst ¤¤ %
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\itshape}   % Opsaetning af tekstdelen ('Figur' eller 'Tabel')
\captiontitlefont{\small}                   % Opsaetning af nummerering
\captiondelim{. }                           % Seperator mellem nummerering og figurtekst
\hangcaption                                % Venstrejusterer flere-liniers figurtekst under hinanden
\captionwidth{\linewidth}                   % Bredden af figurteksten
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}          % Afstand under figurteksten
        
% ¤¤ Opsaetning af listings ¤¤ %
\definecolor{commentGreen}{RGB}{34,139,24}
\definecolor{stringPurple}{RGB}{208,76,239}

\lstset{language=Matlab,                    % Sprog
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,        % Opsaetning af teksten
    keywords={for,if,while,else,elseif,     % Noegleord at fremhaeve
              end,break,return,case,
              switch,function},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},              % Opsaetning af noegleord
    commentstyle=\color{commentGreen},      % Opsaetning af kommentarer
    stringstyle=\color{stringPurple},       % Opsaetning af strenge
    showstringspaces=false,                 % Mellemrum i strenge enten vist eller blanke
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,        % Linjenumre
    extendedchars=true,                     % Tillader specielle karakterer
    columns=flexible,                       % Kolonnejustering
    breaklines, breakatwhitespace=true,     % Bryd lange linjer
}

% ¤¤ Navngivning ¤¤ %
\addto\captionsenglish{
    \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contents}   
    \renewcommand\bibname{References}
    \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendix}
    \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendix}
    \renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}             % Skriver "Kapitel" foran kapitlerne i indholdsfortegnelsen
    \renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}           % Skriver "Appendiks" foran appendiks i indholdsfortegnelsen
}
                                        % ... her

% ¤¤ Sidehoved/sidefod ¤¤ %
\usepackage{lastpage}
\let\footruleskip\undefined
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}}

\fancypagestyle{project}{
\lhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\chead{}
\rhead{my uni}
\lfoot{our solution}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage\ af \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% Redefinition of 'plain' style appearing on chapter pages
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{aolution name}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage\ af \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}

%%%% EGNE KOMMANDOER %%%%

% ¤¤ Billede hack ¤¤ %                                      % Indsaet figurer nemt med \figur{Stoerrelse}{Fil}{Figurtekst}{Label}
\newcommand{\figur}[4]{
        \begin{figure}[H] \centering
            \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{billeder/#2}
            \caption{#3}
            \label{#4}
        \end{figure} 
}

% ¤¤ Specielle tegn ¤¤ %
\newcommand{\decC}{^{\circ}\text{C}}
\newcommand{\dec}{^{\circ}}
\newcommand{\m}{\cdot}

% == INLINE COMMENT == %
\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}

%%%% ORDDELING %%%%
\hyphenation{In-te-res-se e-le-ment}

%%%% TODO-NOTER %%%%
\usepackage{todonotes}

%%%% TABEL BAGGRUNDSFARVER %%%%
\definecolor{aublueclassic}{RGB}{0,61,115}
\definecolor{aubluedark}{RGB}{0,37,70}
\definecolor{aucyan}{RGB}{225,248,253}
%\definecolor{aucyan}{RGB}{55,160,203}
\definecolor{aucyandark}{RGB}{0,62,92}
\definecolor{lightGray}{RGB}{153,153,153}
\definecolor{darkGray}{RGB}{119,119,119}
\definecolor{khaki}{RGB}{240,230,140}
\definecolor{lavender}{RGB}{230,230,250}

%
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{ifthen}

%%%% Tabs %%%%
\usepackage{tabto}
\NumTabs{10}

%%%% REFERENCE TIL SECTION-NAME %%%%
\usepackage{nameref}

%%%% Rotate them tables, son %%%%
\usepackage{rotating}

%%%% For pseudo kode %%%%
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

%%%% string comparison %%%%
\usepackage{xstring}

%%%% KAPITEL UDSEENDE %%%%
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{cabin}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}



%\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\color{aubluedark}\Huge\bfseries\scshape\filleft\lsstyle}{}{0em}{#1\quad\rule[-0.25cm]{1.5pt}{1cm}\rlap{\quad\Huge \thechapter}}
%\titleformat{\chapter}{\thechapter}{\thechapter}{\thechapter}

\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{15pt}}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries\scshape}{}{0em}{\llap{\thesection\quad}\rule[-0.12cm]{1.5pt}{6mm}\quad#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\large\bfseries\scshape}{}{0em}{\thesubsection\quad#1}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\bfseries\scshape}{}{0em}{#1}
```

Comment: Please supply the file `CustomCommand` and a minimum  example that can be compiled.

Comment: Hi @SimonDispa The CustomCommand File only contains stuff related to cross document referencing, and is not relevant here. The above just needs a `main.tex` file including the preamble added and passing `\section*{Figures}` anywhere to gain a working example.

Answer (score 0):

`memoir` might have incompatibilities with `titlesec`. It shows also problems with the * commands. It is better to use the facilities of the first.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside]{memoir}  % Openright aabner kapitler paa hoejresider (openany begge)

%%%% PAKKER %%%%
% ¤¤ Oversaettelse og tegnsaetning ¤¤ %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Input-indkodning af tegnsaet (UTF8)
\usepackage[english]{babel}                 % Dokumentets sprog
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % Output-indkodning af tegnsaet (T1)

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

%\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries\scshape}{}{0em}{\llap{\thesection\quad}\rule[-0.12cm]{1.5pt}{6mm}\quad#1}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}\quad\rule[-0.12cm]{1.5pt}{6mm}}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\scshape}

\begin{document}

\section{Figures 1} 
    
\section*{Figures 2}

\end{document}
```

with `titlesec`

[image: before]

with `memoir`

[image: memo]